# WEG's Star Wars 2nd Ed. d6 system simplification?

Tags: star-wars-d6

**We're preparing for a nostalgic one shot with WEG's d6 Star Wars system,** the one with the "Vader cover", so it's the basic **2nd edition, not the revised one.**

The system seems somewhat dated these days (I'm being diplomatic here), yet we like some aspects of it.

However, rolling handfuls of dice can get boring quick. **How could and should we simplify and speed up the system of the game to keep its fun factor and most of its statistical probabilities as intact as possible?**

Our initial ideas include fixing target numbers for both PCs and NPCs (as in "it's not a range but the upper limit of the range: instead of 6-10, it's always 10"); using dice subtraction instead of opposed rolls in certain cases (subtracting the defense pool of a defender from the attacker's pool with a fixed target number seems to make things easier and faster.) Would these work?

Do you have tips, house rules and/or best practice recommendations?

...or is this a bad idea? :)

Comment: Half the fun of nostalgia gaming is dealing with baroque mechanics.

Comment: Sure, but considering the difficulty of bringing all these players together for a session nowadays (everyone's busy all the time), that's the half we're most willing to let go. We'd rather focus on the story. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Static Target Numbers

Static target numbers are actually the default in 1E; the ranges are shown on the tables in 2E, but generally, just use the high numbers to have the same as in 1E.

From 1st Ed rules:

Very Easy: 5 
Easy 10 
Moderate 15 
Difficult 20 
Very Difficult 30 
Heroic 50+

If you want to have static TN's for opposed rolls, use dice x3 plus the pips. 
*EG: 3d+2 would be (3x3)+2=11; 4d+0 would be 12, etc.

## Other speedups from earlier editions

### Reactions

Dodge, shields, and Parry can be allowed only as reactions - this makes all characters a little less adroit at defense, but is faster to play. Spend an action as a reaction, if made, the roll applies only to that one attack. Any rolls made after take the 1D penalty for multiple actions

Shields as a reaction: rather than angling shields as per 2E, simply roll shields at the time a hit comes in; if dodge+TN from Range or Dodge is greater than the to hit roll, then the shield's dice are applied.

### No Initiative Rolls

Everyone declares actions; everyone rolls their first action - then, in descending order of roll, resolve each action (and make any reaction rolls needed). Then if anyone has second actions, repeat, and so on.

It's actually much quicker, but relies upon people's dice being visually distinct on the table. (It's also from 1E)

### No scaling Tables

The 1E scaling is simpler... the following is an adaptation of it.

**Shooting up a scale:** (personal to walker/speeder; walker/speeder to starfighter; starfighter to capital)

 Smaller rolls double on To hit; 
larger rolls double on hull resistance and shields.

**Shooting up two scales**
Smaller rolls  double to hit, but only 1/3 the damage (0-5d = 1d, 6d-8d rolls 2d, etc)
Larger rolls double on hull and shields, but only 1/3 the pilot or shield skill rolls on defense.

**Shooting down one scale**

Smaller rolls normally

Larger doubles damage rolls

**Shooting down two scales**

Smaller doubles dodge may rolls only 1/3 the dice to resist damage

Larger doubles damage rolls

**Shooting down three scales**

Smaller dies if hit. Dodge doubled

Larger kills on a hit, only rolls 1/3 the dice to hit.

### No CP in play

Don't allow spending Character Points for bonus dice except when resisting damage. One less decision to make.

### Ignore the pips

Treat Pips as just a placeholder to advancement. Ignore the +x when making rolls.

## Borrowing from Star Wars Minaiture Battles...

A simplification used in the miniatures rules reduces things down to 1d6 for all rolls. THe score used is the same as the dice from the RPG. As in a 3d+1 blaster is rolled on 1d6+3 vs the target's dodge.

Note that the mechanics for damage need to be adjusted, as well.

Dam = Res : Stunned  
Dam > Res : Wounded  
Dam ≥ Res +3 : Incapacitated
Dam ≥ Res +6 : Mortal Wound
Dam ≥ Res +9 : dead.
*note: this does not exactly replicate the core nor the SWMB table for same. It's harder to kill unless you open end 6s.*